# Why isn't my quad. equation class working?

Tags: java

My returning values are not coming up as right, and I'm just wondering what I am doing wrong, my code looks fine?!

some of the test that are coming up are:

`Test failed: expected was not equal to actual`

### Expected = 9.000000  and  actual = 0.000000

`The discriminant is not being computed correctly`

`Test failed: expected was not equal to actual`

### Expected = -3.000000  and  actual = 0.000000

```
public class QuadraticEquation {

//coefficients
private double a;
private double b;
private double c;
// created a discriminant instance variable so it's easier to access
// rather than tying out "Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c" every time
// the discriminant is required
private double discriminant = Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);

//constructor
public QuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

//getter for A
public double getA() {
    return a;
}

//getter for B
public double getB() {
    return b;
}

//getter for C
public double getC() {
    return c;
}

// get discriminant
// the discriminant is inside of the square root,
//  and b^2 - 4ac is the expression for the discriminant
public double getDiscriminant() {
    //b^2 - 4ac
    return discriminant;
}

//get root0
public double getRoot0(){
    if (discriminant > 0) {
        return -b + Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2*a;
    }
    return Double.NaN;
}

public double getRoot1() {
    if (discriminant > 0) {
        return -b - Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2*a;
    }
    return Double.NaN;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are fields initialized before constructor code is run in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java) - see especially the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806340/3614835) and apply it to your `discriminant` variable.

Comment: _"created a discriminant instance variable so it's easier to access rather than tying out "Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c" every time
"_ . Why not just put the equation `return Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;` inside method?..Okay, I know you just want to do it in a challenging way :)

Comment: @DnR Presumably because this is what the teacher has told them to do.

Comment: @DavidWallace ah of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to calculate the discriminant before you've set `a`, `b` and `c`, so naturally it's coming out zero.

Move the line that calculates the discriminant down into the constructor.

```
public class QuadraticEquation {

    //coefficients
    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;
    private double discriminant;

    //constructor
    public QuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        discriminant =  b * b - (4 * a * c);
    }

    // etc.
```

Note also that `b * b` generally outperforms `Math.pow(b, 2)` because of the way the latter is calculated.

Also, the operations inside `getRoot0` and `getRoot1` are happening in the wrong order.  You need parentheses to do something like this.

```
public double getRoot0(){
    if (discriminant > 0) {
        return ( -b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    }
    return Double.NaN;
}
```

and similarly in `getRoot1`.

Comment: In other words, Java is an [imperative programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) language, *not* a [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) language.