# Confusion regarding variables in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I am aware about the constructors and what they do?

Suppose there is a class:

```
class Kc
{
 int a=989;
 Kc(int a)
 {
     this.a=a;
 }
 public static void main(String []args)
 {

     Kc obj = new Kc(90);
     System.out.println(obj.a);
 }
}
```

The output of the above program comes out to be 90. My question is this?

Why are we allowed to use the line

```
 int a = 989;
```

The output being 90 means it must have been executed before the constructor is executed so this means that we are assigning a value to an **object's** variable that has not yet been created? I am really confused?

Comment: Your confusion isn't with variables, it's with constructors. A constructor doesn't create an object, it initializes its state.

Comment: Put a 'System.out.println(this.a)' on the line before 'this.a = a' and debug to see what happens.

Comment: @hellyale I did what u said and the result is cause of my confusion.

Comment: Just refresh your page.

Comment: Did it print 989 followed by 90?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The link you provided has some extends keyword? I am beginner in java? So please post appropriate links or remove the duplicate tag.

Comment: @hellyale Yes it did print that.

Comment: Are you asking me if you are a beginner? Being a beginner does not change the fact that the duplicate contains an answer to your question. [EJP's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14806340/438154) in particular explains the exact order of execution for a class' field initializers and constructor.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis PLEASE READ MY QUESTION. I never asked for the order?

Comment: _has not yet been created?_ That implies order. Field initializers are executed before constructor bodies. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Looks like you have developed some communication gap! Let me fill it with words rather than assumptions. All i want is some explanation about why non-static variables are being initialized outside constructor or function? If it was static a I would have completely understood why this was happening because they have nothing to do with objects.

Comment: Because that's how the language works. You can declare instance fields and you can provide them with an initialization expression. If you do, that expression (and the corresponding assignment) is performed before the constructor.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am still giving you a chance to post a better link.

Comment: @JJ put  `if (a > this.a) {this.a = a}` inside the constructor, it should print 989 twice then, maybe that will help clear up the confusion?

Comment: Please elaborate on that by posting an answer.  THATS HOW THE LANGUAGE WORKS shows lack of insight.

Comment: @JJ when they mark a question as duplicate it cannot be answered.

Comment: If you don't think the linked duplicate answers your question, edit your question with more details clarifying what your actual question is and what hasn't been addressed by the link. Others can vote to re-open the question.