# Java - Method executed prior to Default Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm learning java and accidentally I came across following code where default constructor is executed after the method.

```
public class ChkCons {

    int var = getVal();

    ChkCons() {
        System.out.println("I'm Default Constructor.");
    }

    public int getVal() {
        System.out.println("I'm in Method.");
        return 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ChkCons c = new ChkCons();

    }

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
I'm in Method.
I'm Default Constructor.
```

Can anyone please explain me why this happened?

Thanks.

Comment: The fields are initialised before the constructor is called, since you're field initialisation calls the `getVal` method, it is called before the constreuctor

Comment: Alright, then getVal() will it execute before the STATIC BLOCK also?

Comment: The constructor?  No, but a `static` block (from memory) will execute once before the fields

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Instance variable initialization expressions such as `int var = getVal();` are evaluated after the super class constructor is executed but prior to the execution of the current class constructor's body.

Therefore `getVal()` is called before the body of the `ChkCons` constructor is executed.

Comment: Alright, then getVal() will it execute before the STATIC BLOCK also?

Comment: @RohitNigam No, the static initializer block is executed when the class is initialized. That takes place before any individual instance of the class is initialized.

Comment: @RohitNigam How could it? It requires *an instance*. There's no instance in a static block. Just think about it for a second.

Comment: @Holger Perhaps my wording was inaccurate.  I meant the instance variable initializations take place before the code of the current class's constructor is executed. I said nothing about when the code of the super class's constructor is executed.

Comment: you should keep `getVal()` as a static method.

Comment: The wording is incorrect, as noted by @Holger, and should be fixed *in the answer*. Clarifying in comments is not sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

Constructor is called prior to method. The execution of method occurs after that which is a part of object creation in which instance variables are evaluated. This could be better understand from following code.

```
class SuperClass{
    SuperClass(){
        System.out.println("Super constructor");
    }
}
public class ChkCons extends SuperClass{

    int var = getVal();

    ChkCons() {
        System.out.println("I'm Default Constructor.");
    }

    public int getVal() {
        System.out.println("I'm in Method.");
        return 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ChkCons c = new ChkCons();

    }

}
```

The above code has following output

```
Super constructor
I'm in Method.
I'm Default Constructor.
```

Here the compiler automatically adds `super();` as the first statement in `ChkCons()` constructor, and hence it is called prior to the `getVal()` method.

Answer (score 2):

We can refer the following oracle documentation on Initializing instance variables (Emphasis is mine):

> Initializing Instance Members
>
> Normally, you would put code to initialize an instance variable in a
>   constructor. **There are two alternatives to using a constructor to
>   initialize instance variables: initializer blocks and final methods.**
>
> **Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static
>   initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:**
>
> {
>       // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here }
>
> **> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors.**
>
> A final method cannot be overridden in a subclass. This is discussed
>   in the lesson on interfaces and inheritance. Here is an example of
>   using a final method for initializing an instance variable:
>
> ```
> class Whatever {
> private varType myVar = initializeInstanceVariable();
>
> protected final varType initializeInstanceVariable() {
>
>     // initialization code goes here
> } 
> }
> ```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create an instance of a class instance variables are initialized first followed by execution of the Constructor

Ref : [Are fields initialized before constructor code is run in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class InitializerIndex {

    public InitializerIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Default Constructor");
    }

    static {

        System.out.println("Static Block one");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Init one");
    }

    void letsRoll() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InitializerIndex().letsRoll();
        new InitializerIndex().letsRoll();
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Init Two");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("Static Block two");
    }

}
```

Will have following output:

```
Static Block one
Static Block two
Init one
Init Two
Default Constructor
Init one
Init Two
Default Constructor
```

First all the static content is loaded, then the instance content. Static content is loaded only once.

**Even when two objects are created, the static block is called only when the first object is created**.

Also, at the time of object creation or in constructors, if you want to use methods like this

```
 int var = getVal();
```

You should use static methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are initializing the method into a field using `int var = getVal();`, so it will execute before constructor call.
Static block have the first priority, it executes during loading of class.