# Field value not set when using mock and abstract class

Tags: android, unit-testing, constructor, mocking, abstract-class

For some unexplainable reason a field (`currentExp`) I'm assigning in the constructor isn't correctly set while using a mock for my unittest. I'm assigning the field `currentExp` by loading it via the `loadExperience` method using my `Storage` class (which uses SharedPreferences). When I'm unittesting this, I'd like to mock the `Storage` class, so `loadexperience` returns a value of 10.

Here's my concrete `Experience` class:

```
public class Experience extends StorageObject {

    private int currentExp = 0;

    public Experience() {
        this(new Storage());
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected Experience(Storage storage) {
        super(storage);
    } // Debug point #2

    @Override
    protected void init(Storage storage) {
        this.currentExp = storage.loadExperience();
    } // Debug point #1
}
```

It extends `StorageObject`:

```
public abstract class StorageObject {
    protected Storage storage;

    protected StorageObject() {
        this(new Storage());
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected StorageObject(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
        init(storage);
    }

    protected abstract void init(Storage storage);
}
```

And this is my unittest:

```
@Test
public void testConstructor_StorageValuePositive_IsSetAsCurrentExp() {
    int expectedSavedExp = 10;
    Storage storageMock = mock(Storage.class);
    doReturn(expectedSavedExp).when(storageMock).loadExperience();

    Experience exp = new Experience(storageMock);

    assertEquals(expectedSavedExp, exp.getCurrentExp());
}
```

While debugging I found out the mock DOES work, and the value of 10 is assigned to `currentExp` at Debug point #1. Then shortly afterwards, at Debug point #2 the value seems to be 0 again.

Anyone got a clue what is happening here, and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the initialization order. The super constructor happens first then the field initialization.

So your constructor sets the `currentExp` in it's super call to 10 then the field gets initilized with 0.

So what can you do? Some ideas:
Move the `currentExp` to the parent class or don't give it a default value.

More reading material:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806340/5842844

Comment: Great, thanks!
I guess you mean `currentExp` instead of `expectedSavedExp`? ;-)
But I got the idea how to solve it, that's what matters. ...

Another idea: because I've set `storage` as a field in `StorageObject`, I could also initialize `currentExp` with `storage.loadExperience()` as default value, instead of assigning it in the constructor. In that way I can also leave out the `abstract init` method.
That appears to solve the unittest problem, but is it common / correct to do so?

Comment: ups yes I meant currentExp. You could just move the init into the child class there is no reason for that to be on the parent.