# Why does getContext() work but context passed in through constructor does not work?

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I have defined my own Array Adapter class called WordAdapter. Here is my code

```
Context context;
int backgroundColor;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int backgroundColor) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, words);
    this.context = context;
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}

private AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

The above code produces a Null Pointer Exception.

But this code does not:

```
Context context;
int backgroundColor;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int backgroundColor) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, words);
    this.context = context;
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}

private AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Why does the context passed through the constructor not work?

**EDIT**I call it in different activities, one of it is given below:

```
itemsAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words, R.color.category_numbers);
```

where `itemsAdapter` is declared as a `WordAdapter` and `words` is a ArrayList of `Word` class items.

Comment: plz show us where you are calling the constructor

Comment: Move `audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);` inside method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I defined context as a global variable. Can you please explain (as an answer) why your method would work?

Comment: @SiddharthVenu Visualise these variables not as Global variables but as instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to prosperK's comment, what you are doing is creating and initializing the variable at the same time. That means context is still null when you created audioManager Variable.

One work around is initialize the audioManager in the contructor when your context will actually have a value.

Comment: But I have `context` as a global variable, whose value I set to be equal to the local variable `context`. Why would the global `context`'s value be null?

Comment: Your global variable will remain null unless you provide it with some value. Value is given in constructor. So, unless constructor is called its null. The fact is your global variables context and audioManager are created at the same time that is you are using same null context to initialize audioManager

Comment: Thank you do much. Got it :)

Answer (score 2):

Because fields are initialized to their default values before the constructor runs. Your `audioManager` field initialization depends on `context` which is only initialized in constructor.

You should move the `audioManager` initialization to your constructor if it depends on a constructor argument.

Apparently your `getContext()` returns a `Context` that is valid at field initialization phase.

See also: [Are fields initialized before constructor code is run in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

initialize audioManager in constructor.