# Android custom click listener inline vs field decleration why

Tags: java

If I set a custom click listener within the method decleration it works.
But if I define the custom click listener as a private field and set it, it doesn't work. why?

```
public class CustomView {

  private View mView;
  private Button mButton;

  public CustomView() {
    mButton = new Button();
    mView = new View();
    // this works
    mView.setOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick() {
         mButton.setText("xyz");
       }
    });

    // this doesn't work as in nothing happens.
    mView.setOnClickListener(mCustomListener);
  }

  private CustomClickListener mCustomListener = new CustomClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick() {
     mButton.setText("xyz");
   }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the order in which things happen. What will happen is:

First your constructor starts running, basically making a super call.

**Then** all your fields are initialized, so *mCustomListener* is init'ed **before** your assign a value to mButton!

One way to fix this:

```
private final mButton = new Button();
private final mCustomerListener = ...
```

and then within your ctor, just do the

```
mView.setOnClickListener(mCustomListener);
```

So, in other words: the problem with your code is that the **field** init for *mCustomListener* runs **before** you init mButton.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java) for further details on "order".

(hint: I recommend to make any fields *final*, simply because that is a good practice. Only allow fields to be changed later on ... when there is a good reason to do so; otherwise, keep your stuff final).

Comment: I init the field, before the onClick is fired, so that doesn't matter?

Comment: hmm, now that you say that ... well, maybe you should be more specific in your question about how "it doesn't work" manifests itself.