# ArrayList add method compiling but not working

Tags: java, arraylist

I keep looking through the code for this, but I can't find anything that would seem off. I'm new to programming so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but any help would be appreciated. The assignment I'm working on is to make a 52 card deck and then design methods to change the deck, the cards are being created but are not being added to the ArrayList. My code for the deck class is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class FiftyTwoCardDeck
{
List<Card> totalDeck = new ArrayList<>();

private int deckSize = totalDeck.size();

public FiftyTwoCardDeck()
{
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
        for(int k=0;k<13;k++) {
            String s;
            String c;

            switch(j) {
                case 0:
                s = "Spades";
                break;

                case 1:
                s = "Diamonds";
                break;

                case 2:
                s = "Clubs";
                break;

                case 3:
                s = "Hearts";
                break;
            }

            switch(k) {
                case 0:
                c = "Ace";
                break;

                case 10:
                c = "Jack";
                break;

                case 11:
                c = "Queen";
                break;

                case 12:
                c = "King";
                break;

                default:
                c = ""+(k+1);
                break;
            }

            Card card = new Card(s, c);
            totalDeck.add(card);
        }
    }
}

    public int cardAmount()
    {
        return deckSize;
    }
}
```

The tester class just creates an object:

```
public class FiftyTwoCardDeckTester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        FiftyTwoCardDeck deck = new FiftyTwoCardDeck();
    }
}
```

And the card class that makes objects for the deck is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Card
{
    public Card(String st, String ct)
    {
        suit = st;
        count = ct;
    }

    public String getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    public String getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public String suit;
    public String count;
}
```

Comment: Your deckSize is always zero. You should return `totalDeck.size()` in your `cardAmount` method

Comment: To help you learn the language, you should learn how to debug the language through break points and a normal debugger. Check out how this article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, very grateful. I'll check out the debugging link DogEatDog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private int deckSize = totalDeck.size();

public int cardAmount()
{
    return deckSize;
}
```

You're initializing `deckSize` when a `FiftyTwoCardDeck` object is created. It's is set to 0 before the constructor is run and never updated. You need to update it when cards are added to the deck.

Or, delete the variable and have `cardAmount()` ask the list how big it is every time it's called.

```
public int cardAmount()
{
    return totalDeck.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem.

```
private int deckSize = totalDeck.size();
```

This field is initialized before the constructor body is executed. See this answer for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806340/342852

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `List` is being inflated with `Cards` however `cardAmount()` will always return `0` because `deckSize` is intiated to `0` at the creation of `FiftyTwoCardDeck`.

Use this instead:

```
public int cardAmount()
{
    return totalDeck.size()
}
```