# Java concurrency - inline initialized non-final field and safe publication

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-memory-model

Assume I have the following class:

```
public abstract class Test {
    private List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

    // to be called concurrently
    public int getStringsSize() {
        return strings.size();
    }
}
```

Is there a chance that `getStringsSize()` will throw NPE for some subclass of `Test`? Or what else can go wrong? As far as I understand there're no Java Memory Model guarantees about such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is: when a subclass object gets instantiated, the super constructor and super *field init* statements will be executed **before** any subclass code is executed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation) for more information. In other words: before a *client* that creates a subclass via new gets access to the newly created object, it is guaranteed that those init statements were executed.

And as we are talking about a single **private** field that only lives in the super class, there is no chance for that method call to produce an NPE

Unless you have some other method that resets the field to null. Which you can avoid by using the **final** keyword for that field (which is good practice anyway: make it your *default* to put **final** on fields).

Finally; for completeness: it is possible to write super/subclass code that fails when doing `new` on the subclass because of "something not initialized yet" - like when your super class constructor calls a method that is **overridden** in the subclass. But that is like: bad practice (as it can lead to such bizarre errors). So don't even think about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

No. As long as the `strings` field is not reassigned (which can never be done by a subclass since it is private), then it will never be accessed in a null state, no matter how many threads try to access it. And as such, `strings.size()` can never throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

`getStringSize()` would only throw NPE if you set `strings` to `null` manually, EG in a `setStrings()` method. `getStringSize()` should also be set `final`.

The initializer runs at instantiation time, that is after the `super(...)` constructor, but before the first instruction of `this(...)` constructor.