# Java value is always null?

Tags: java, class, oop, nullpointerexception, null

I have a value in Java that is always null but I don't understand why, because I am setting the value of the variable using the class constructor.

I have code like such:

```
Driver driverClass = new Driver("<file path redacted>");
```

And then the below:

```
String cfgFilePath;

public Driver(String cfgFile) {
    this.cfgFilePath = cfgFile;
}

private ArrayList<String> keys = getKeys(cfgFilePath);
private String a1 = keys.get(0);
private String b1 = keys.get(1);
```

For some reason, IntelliJ IDEA says that cfgFilePath is always null. I am initializing it with the Driver class constructor, so why is it null? When I run the program I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806340/2864740 (direct relevant answer in related question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the initialization of `keys`, `a1` and `b1` to your constructor like:

```
public Driver(String cfgFile) {
    this.cfgFilePath = cfgFile;
    this.keys = getKeys(cfgFilePath);
    this.a1 = keys.get(0);
    this.b1 = keys.get(1);
}

private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
private String a1;
private String b1;
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! But I'd like to know how. I read the other post's explanation of the order of initialization but I am still confused as to why that means that those variables are always null at all times.

Comment: These attributes are null because your attribute `keys` does need `cfgFilePath` to work properly. You set `cfgFilePath` within your constructor but the `keys` attribute tries to initialize its attribute  **before** you call the constructor and at this time the `cfgFilePath` is not set (the String attribute is `null` per default if it's not initialized). You have a predefined order of execution you want to achieve -> 1. set `cfgFilePath` and 2. initialize the other attributes.