# Instantiate array of objects with a variable

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote some classes in Java but when I run the program I receive the error "`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`", the incriminate class is this:

```
public class Bank {

    private String name;
    private int maxbankaccount;
    private int activebankaccount;
    private String radice = "IT8634";
    private Conto[] bankaccount = new Conto[maxbankaccount];

    public void addconto(String cf) {
        bankaccount[activebankaccount] = new Conto(radice + activebankaccount , cf);
        activebankaccount++;
    }

    public Bank(String name, int maxbankaccount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.maxbankaccount = maxbankaccount;
    }
}
```

I wrote a tester class to test :

```
public class TestBank {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Bank b1 = new Bank("Fidelity", 10);

        b1.addconto("PROVA");
    }
}
```

Since I didn't seem to have made logical errors using the array I debugged, I realized that in the creation of the array of objects the `maxbankaccount`  variable isn't 10 (value passed in Test) but as default value (0),then I tried passing 10 directly and it works good. Why is not the value 10 of `maxbankaccount` passed but 0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are fields initialized before constructor code is run in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Conto[] bankaccount = new Conto[maxbankaccount];
```

This initialization takes place *before* the rest of the constructor runs.

Move it into the constructor:

```
public Bank(String name, int maxbankaccount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.maxbankaccount = maxbankaccount;
    this.bankaccount = new Conto[maxbankaccount];
}
```

Comment: Further, if you were to declare the `maxbankaccount` field as `final` then you would get a compiler error to protect you against pre-initialized usage bug.

Answer (score 1):

You have indeed made a logical error. The array `bankaccount` is getting initialized when the class is instantiated and is always 0.

Move it into the constructor and initialize it.

```
public Bank(String name, int maxbankaccount) {
    /* ... */
    this.bankaccount = new Conto[maxbankaccount];
}
```

Comment: It's not static, so it doesn't get executed when the class is loaded; rather it gets executed on instantiation but before the constructor.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Further more than the issues that are in the other answers, this

```
private int activebankaccount;
```

does not initialize the variable `activebankaccount`
So in:

```
public void addconto(String cf) {
    bankaccount[activebankaccount] = new Conto(radice + activebankaccount , cf);
    activebankaccount++;
}
```

you are using an uninitialized vale as index of the array `bankaccount`