# A question on Java constructor and class member initialization

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to understand why the output of the following Java code is as like this:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.print("A()");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
class B {
    public B() {
        System.out.print("B()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
class C extends A {
    B b = new B();
}

public class E05SimpleInheritance {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new C();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"A()B()"
```

I would imagine that when the main method of the E05SimpleInheritance public class is called the following things should happen

1. Non-public class C is loaded and its fields are initialized(before calling the default constructor of class C)
2. Since its member 'b' is an object of class B, class B is loaded in memory
3. Since we construct an object of Class B its constructor is called which should print B()
4. Default constructor of C is called which automatically calls the constructor of the superclass A which print A()

So the final output should be B()A() which is obviously wrong so I do not really understand how the code flows in this case. Can you perhaps show me why is A()B() printed instead of B()A()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are fields initialized before constructor code is run in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in step 1:

> Non-public class C is loaded and its fields are initialized(before calling the default constructor of class C)

This is *not* what’s happening. In reality, non-static fields are initialised *at the beginning* of the constructor, not *before* it. And the base class constructor is implicitly (or explicitly) invoked even *before that*.

In other words, `javac` generates code for `C` which is equivalent to the following:

```
class C extends A {
    B b;

    C() {
        super();
        b = new B();
    }
}
```