# Why java member variable initialization can use “this ” keyword

Tags: java

When I read spring source code, class "AbstractApplicationContext" has a field:

```
private String id = ObjectUtils.identityToString(this);
```

I have a doubt, method `identityToString(this)` is executed before class `AbstractApplicationContext` is instantiated. Why "this" keyword can be used at this time?

As I understand, `this` represents the AbstractApplicationContext instance, before AbstractApplicationContext is instantiated, `this` cannot be used.

Can someone answer my doubts?

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java

Comment: It is not _"executed before class AbstractApplicationContext is instantiated"_, it is executed during initialization, the object represented by `this` already exists at that point (it might just not be fully initialized).

Comment: it is explicitly allowed in the [Java Language Specification 15.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3-100-D): "**The keyword this may be used as an expression in the following contexts:** ...  in the initializer of an instance variable of a class" ||| BTW the instance is being initialized at that specific moment, and the first step is allocating memory, before executing any code, so `this` already got its value (reference) ||| sure, such call is dangerous and eventually cause problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different stages in class loading and object instantiating. Let's look at the latter, because this is interesting for you.

The following steps are executed:

1. A memory area is allocated for the object. It has a reference, it will be associated with the newly created object. It is the `this` reference, and as you can see, it works from the very first step.
2. Then all the fields are initialized and all the instance blocks are run (these are the `{ }` blocks within the class definition). If starts with the `Object` class, then in all descendant classes, lastly the instantiated class.
3. Finally the constructor is called - it is not constructing the object, opposing to its name, it only *initializes* it, with the given parameters. The constructor calls the `super` constructor as the first step - ultimately the `Object` constructor is executed first, then the descendants, lastly the constructor of the instantiated class.

Actually it's a bad technique to access `this` before the end of the constructor, it even has a name: **leaking this**.

Comment: step 1.5: explicit/implicit call of superclass constructor(s) (and same steps 1.5, 2 and 3 for that superclass) unless the class is `Object` - [JLS 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

Comment: @user16320675 Thanks for the addendum, it's partly true. The fields are initialized, but the constructor is called at step 3 - that's why the `super` call must be the first call in each constructor. (There may be multiple super constructors). Changed the text.

Comment: "partly true" - what exactly is wrong? the superclass constructor is executed before the fields and instance initializers of the current class is executed (sure it is even more complicated, some steps/cases omitted...)

Comment: BTW simple prove on [IDEone](https://ideone.com/atYyZM) - we see that the super constructor is called before step 2 ! Otherwise the Java Language Specification - I added the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) in first comment - is wrong... probably since last millennium (?) ||| kind of *logial* to have the superclass fully initialized before starting to initialize the child class