# How objects are created and initialized in detail

Tags: java, recursion, heap-memory, stack-overflow, stack-memory

I don't understand the ***logic*** of why the code results in stackOverFlow error:

```
public class Human {
    private String name;
    private int age = 30;
    private Human human = new Human();
    

    public Human() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human h = new Human();
    }
}
```

Please correct me if i'm wrong. When we write:

```
Human h = new Human();
```

The main method and the h reference variable will be pushed into the stack. Then the *new* keyword will first create a human object with the default values, that is a human object with the field: name = null, age = 30 will be created... BUT once the JVM encounters:

```
 private Human human = new Human();
```

Then the human reference variable will be pushed into the stack. Then the *new* keyword will create  a human object again with the default values: name = null , age = 30 and then when the JVM encounters:

```
private Human human = new Human();
```

Then the human reference variable will again be pushed into the stack and then the new keyword will again created a new human object with the default values etc.

***PLESE NOTE:*** I haven't mentioned the constructor because the constructor is invoked *after a human object has been created with all its default values* hence when i execute the program, "hello world" (the body of the constructur) is **NOT** printed into the console...

So, what i am saying is: **The reason of why the program results in stackOverFlow error is because of the reference variable human** and not because of a lot of constructor invocations.

**However**, everywhere i read about this example, they always say that it is because of a lot of constructor invocations that results in stackOverFlow error.... constructors initialize the state of an object but how in the world can a constructor initialize an object if the object hasn't even been created yet ?  that is why i believe that first the new keyword creates an object with the default values and THEN the constructor initialize the state of that object... but with that in mind, i cannot understand how it is the constructor that is the reason of the stackOverFlow error

When i tested the program for the first time, i expected OutOfMemoryError because the program leads to a lot of human objects being created... however, the program also results in a lot of human reference variables being pushed into the stack (and the stack has a fixed size i believe whereas the heap can grow so it makes sense that the program results in stackOverFlow before OutOfMemoryError).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are fields initialized before constructor code is run in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java)

Comment: Based on the above link, I think that every time the Human() constructor is called, it does the super(), then initializes the field variable human, which then calls the Human() constructor which recursively keeps going and ends up in SO.

Comment: There is also an answer in that link that shows how after compilation, the initialization of the human field variable is __moved__ inside the constructor, so your constructor will become `public Human() {
        human = new Human();
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }`

Comment: So, are you guys saying that first the new keyword creates an object (but it hasn't given its defualt values yet) then super() is called  (which is inside the constructur and hence it invokes the constructur) BUT after it has invoked super() then the the default values of the obejct is given: that is name = null, age = 30 and THEN the JVM encounters:  private Human human = new Human(); , which again results in a human object being created without its defualt values, then super() is invoked which is inside the constructur and hence another constructur invocation is pushed into the stack etc. ?

Comment: check Java Language Specification [15.9.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Class Instance Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4): "... space is allocated for the new class instance ... The new object contains new instances of all the fields ... Next, the selected constructor of the specified class is invoked. ..."

Comment: 1. Human object is created without its default values,  2. super() is called, which is inside the body of the constructor and hence the constructor is called and hence being pushed into the stack. 3. After the super() invocation, the default values of the object is given. 4. When the default values of the human object is given (name = null, age = 30) , the JVM encounters:   private Human human = new Human();  and hence a new human object is created and hence another constructor is pushed into the stack etc. this is why the program throws stackOverFlow  am i correct ?

Comment: The respond above is also the reason why the program doesn't print "hello word" into the console... because AFTER the object has been provided with its default values THEN the rest of the code inside the constructor, which is   System.out.println("hello world"); will be executed... 

Comment: "So, what i am saying is: The reason of why the program results in stackOverFlow error is because of the reference variable human and not because of a lot of constructor invocations." - this distinction makes no sense. The "reference variable human" (i.e., the fact that there is a field which is initialized with a `new Human()`) **is the cause of** the constructor invocations.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your question fundamentally stems from a misunderstanding of how constructors and inline field initialization work. When you have the following:

```java
public class Human {

  private String name;
  private int age = 30;
  private Human human = new Human();

  public Human() {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```

The inline initialization of the `age` and `human` fields happen *during* construction. The byte-code initializing those fields is quite literally *in the constructor*, despite the source code making it appear otherwise. In other words, the above is equivalent to the following:

```java
public class Human extends Object {

  private String name;
  private int age;
  private Human human;

  public Human() {
    super();
    age = 30;
    human = new Human(); // line 10
    System.out.println("Hello, World!"); // line 11
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `Human` constructor is *recursively* invoking the same constructor on line 10. A new stack frame is allocated for the calling thread every time this constructor is invoked. Eventually the thread runs out of stack memory and a `StackOverflowError` is thrown. And since the error is thrown on line 10, you will not see "Hello, World!" printed to the standard output stream, because line 11 will never be reached.

As an aside, note that the *default values*<sup>1</sup> for fields are set before the constructor is invoked. At a high level<sup>2</sup>, when you use `new` the following happens:

1. Memory is allocated for the new object based on the object's type.
2. All instance fields of the object are set to their default values by the JVM.
3. The constructor is invoked.
4. Unless the current constructor is for `java.lang.Object`, the superclass's constructor is invoked, going back to step 3.
5. All instance initializer blocks and inline instance field initializations defined for the current class are invoked in the order they appear in the source code.
6. The code explicitly in the constructor body is invoked.
7. The constructor returns.

In the `Human` example above, the constructor is recursively constructing more `Human` objects at step 5.

---

<sup>1. The default values are: `null` for object types; `0` for number primitives; and `false` for booleans.</sup>

<sup>2. It can get a little more complex than this due to constructors being able to delegate to other constructors and choose *which* super constructor gets invoked. However, both delegating to other constructors and explicitly invoking a super constructor must be the first statement of the constructor<sup>**</sup>. That means the superclass's constructor **will** have been invoked before step 5.</sup>

<sup>** At least for now. See [JEP 447: Statements before super(...) (Preview)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/447) (such statements will not be allowed to reference `this`; they are meant to facilitate argument validation before invoking a super constructor).</sup>

Comment: adding one detail - the `StackOverflow` is probably happening *instead* of the `OutOfMemory` because the stack is *smaller* than the heap