# Declaring Member Class Variables and Instantiating Them

Tags: java

I'm used to C++, where you have to instantiate everything in the constructer, but a recent realization has made me very confused about java. I was just instantiating things in the constructer, and then I realized this syntax was valid:

```
public class DebateCompetition {
    private boolean isAdvanced;
    ArrayList<Debate> debates = new ArrayList<Debate>(); //<------
    ArrayList<Team> teams;
    ArrayList<School> schools;

    public void addSchool(School s) {
        schools.add(s);
    }
}
```

But that leaves a lot of questions. First: What does it do? Second: When is `new ArrayList<Debate>()` called? Third: Is this a best practice, or not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916735/default-constructor-vs-inline-field-initialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First: What does it do?

All field initializers are executed (in order) before the code in the constructor is executed.  (In this case you haven't declared a constructor, so there is a default no-args constructor which invokes the superclasses no-args constructor.)

> Second: When is new ArrayList() called?

It is called during the instantiation of a new object.

The call happens after the superclass constructor has completed, and before executing the statements in this classes constructor.  (In this case there are no statements in the constructor.)

> Third: Is this a best practice, or not?

It is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's the equivalent of innitializing these variables at the beginning of a constructor. If, in addition, you are using an instance initialization block, they are initialized before the initialization block is invoked. After executing the superclass constructor the order is: fields initialized in the class body, initialization blocks, the constructor body. If you only declare fields in the class body, the compiler automatically initializes them anyway, to their default values: null for Object, false for boolean etc.