# Android activity stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am trying to use `SharedPreference` to store some values and access them later, but don't know why my `Activity` crashed and giving me this error.

```
06-12 11:03:40.459    1525-1525/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ets.medecord/com.ets.medecord.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:353)
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:348)
            at com.ets.medecord.SplashActivity.<init>(SplashActivity.java:15)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code which I am using in my `SplashActivity.java`.
when I run my app it crashes but if I remove those lines containing `SharedPreference`.

```
public class SplashActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
static final int PAUSE_TIME = 2000;
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
boolean isAppFirstStart = pref.getBoolean("start",true);
Handler handler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    handler = new Handler();
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(PAUSE_TIME);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(isAppFirstStart) {
                        editor.putBoolean("start",false);
                        editor.commit();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IntroActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Try putting those shared preference lines in your onCreate().

Comment: @hungryghost already done it.

Comment: Moving those lines should fix your error. You'll have to make `pref` and `editor` final as they are used in an inner class.

Comment: `SplashActivity.java:15` Which is this line?

Comment: @MatterCat  but why android studio don't these as problem. cause whenever I use any other variable in inner class it suggest to make it final but this time it won't showing anything like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. You're saying that it's not asking you to make them final? I plugged your code into Android Studio and it shows squiggly little lines under `editor`, hence the "use final" suggestion. If you fixed it differently, though, what matters more if it works or not. Is it working now?

Comment: @MatterCat it is working now without using final.

Comment: Cool, then, no need to worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Move your shared preference lines to onCreate, like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    ...
}
```

Then it will work.

The reason `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` was giving you a null pointer exception, is because `this` cannot be resolved before `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2):

Outside class methods and in [static initialization blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks), `this` is `null`. It hasn't been initialized yet.

Thus, you can't pass `this` in such places.

[Default constructor vs. inline field initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4916735/1841194)