# how do I make a class that accepts a file name and can print its contents?

Tags: java, file, printing, constructor

I'm having problems making a class that can read and print from a file. It seems like the file name passed to the constructor isn't actually being assigned to the fileName variable, or maybe I'm doing something wrong with the File and Scanner objects. I really don't know what's wrong or how to fix it. I'm a beginner and just covered using files in my class, so I'm probably missing something obvious. Thanks for any help anyone can give :)

Here's all my code and the instructions for the assignment below.

The assignment was to:

> Write a class named FileDisplay with the following methods:
>
> - constructor: accepts file name as argument
> - displayHead: This method should display only the first five lines of the file’s contents. If the file contains less than five lines, it should display the file’s entire contents.
> - displayContents: This method should display the entire contents of the file, the name of which was passed to the constructor.
> - displayWithLineNumbers: This method should display the contents of the file, the name of which was passed to the constructor. Each line should be preceded with a line number followed by a colon. The line numbering should start at 1.

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileDisplay {  
    
    // just using little random .txt files to test it
    private String fileName = "example1.txt";
    
    public FileDisplay(String fileName) throws IOException {
        this.fileName = fileName;   
    }
    
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    
    // displays first 5 lines of file
    public void displayHead() {         
        for (int x = 0; x < 5 && inputFile.hasNext(); x++) {
            System.out.println(" " + inputFile.nextLine());
        }
    }
    
    //displays whole file
    public void displayContents() {     
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(" " + inputFile.nextLine());
        }
    }
    
    // displays whole file with line numbers
    public void displayWithLineNumbers() {      
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            int x = 1;
            System.out.println(x + ": " + inputFile.nextLine());
            x++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FileDisplay [someFile=" + fileName + "]";
    }

}
```

I also wrote a driver application to test if the class was working or not:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileDisplayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        PrintWriter ex1 = new PrintWriter("example1.txt");
        ex1.println("apple");
        ex1.println("pear");
        ex1.println("grape");
        ex1.close();
        
        FileDisplay test = new FileDisplay("example1.txt");
        test.displayContents();         
        System.out.println(test.toString());        
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting `File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);` inside the constructor, or they won't use the chosen file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
```

That statement is **outside** of your constructor.

It is executed **before** the constructor kicks in. Therefore the file object is created with the wrong (your default!) name! (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916735/default-constructor-vs-inline-field-initialization) for further reading)

The better approach here: make your fields **final**, and use "constructor telescoping"; like this:

```
private final String fileName;
private final Scanner scanner;

public FileDisplay() {
  this("default.txt");
}

public FileDisplay(String fileName) {
  this.fileName = fileName;
  this.scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
}
```

And now the compiler **helps** you making sure that your fields get initialized exactly once, in the order that you put down **once** in your constructor. And you skill have the opportunity to create a FileDisplay object using some "default" file name (where, actually: I would recommend to not do that).

Comment: Thank you! That really helped. About the default file name, I just had that in there because it wouldn't work at all without it.