# Inline field initialization

Tags: nim-lang

Is there a syntax to auto generate constructors from inline initial values of object-type's members in nim ?
In the like of C++11/java

c.f. [Default constructor vs. inline field initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4916735/893406)

imaginary syntax:

```
type
  MyT = object of RootObj
    str* = "<initial>"
```

for the moment the build outputs

> initialization not allowed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have to write down the constructor explicitly, this too has to be done explicitly. You could write a macro to do it automatically though.

```
type
  MyT = object of RootObj
    str*: string

proc initMyT(str = "<initial>"): MyT =
  result.str = str
```