# Differences in these two ways of initializing instance variables?

Tags: java

I just realized I've been initializing instance variables in the following way:

```
public class Service{
    private Resource resource;

    public Service(){
        resource = new Resource();
        //other stuff...
    }
}
```

...out of just being used to it, I guess.

I was wondering if this leads to any differences in instantiation, compilation, or anything I'm not realizing about, with the following way of doing it:

```
public class Service{
    private Resource resource = new Resource();

    public Service(){
        //other stuff...
    }
}
```

I do realize that there's an advantage in the first way of doing it in case you might want different "default" values, as in the following case:

```
public class Foo{
    private String bar;
    private SomeClass bar2;

    public Foo(){
        bar = "";
        bar2 = new SomeClass();
        //other stuff...
    }

    public Foo(String bar, SomeClass bar2){
        this.bar = bar;
        this.bar2 = bar2;
        //other stuff...
    }
}
```

vs

```
public class Foo{
    private String bar = "";
    private SomeClass bar2 = new SomeClass();

    public Foo(){
        //other stuff...
    }

    public Foo(String bar, SomeClass bar2){
        this.bar = bar;
        this.bar2 = bar2;
        //other stuff...
    }
}
```

...since the latter one makes instances of the variables that will get trashed if the parameterized constructor is called, but this is a more "complex" case and probably the reason I got used to the former way of initializing instances.

Are there any advantages about either way aside from getting used to one of them for when it really counts?

Comment: You can probably find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916735/default-constructor-vs-inline-field-initialization

Comment: Ah, there it is. I couldn't find it when I searched, it definitely is a duplicate question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration-site initializations are compiled into all the constructors, in the order they appear. So the only difference between the two approaches is that declaration-site initialization gets "reused", which (as you point out) is convenient but can also be wasteful. Your second example is equivalent to:

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar;
    private SomeClass bar2;

    public Foo() {
        this.bar = "";
        this.bar2 = new SomeClass();
        // other stuff...
    }

    public Foo(String bar, SomeClass bar2) {
        this.bar = "";
        this.bar2 = new SomeClass();
        this.bar = bar;
        this.bar2 = bar2;
        // other stuff...
    }
}
```

(By the way: please put a space before your `{`, unless you're at a company with a coding standard that says not to.)